# Double for loop python huge matrix - parallelizing

Tags: python, numpy, loops, optimization, parallel-processing

I have to iterate over each cell of a 200x200 array in order to change the value of the cells taking into account the values of the prior-column neighbours.
Basically, what I am trying to do is to **randomly place Gaussian-like distribution values on an array**, with a certain probability, and **I would like to reduce the time of this operation** because if I increase my array it takes too long to generate this updated array.

I am doing a directed-percolation-like distribution by "hand" where if a cell (cell2) is touching a full cell (cell1) in the column before, the first (cell2) becomes full affecting its surroundings.

This is my code:

```
def normaldist(x, y, Nx, Ny, xp, yp, SG=1):
    """2D-mesh (Nx, Ny) with Gaussian-like distribution values."""
    z = np.exp(-0.5*(((x-xp)**2 + (y - yp)**2)/SG**2))
# / (SG*np.sqrt(np.pi*2.)))
    return z


def distributionG(Nx, Ny, xp, yp, SG=1):
    """Fill up the C0(Nx, Ny) array for the specified values and conditions."""
    mask = np.zeros((Nx, Ny))
    for j in range(0, Ny):
        for i in range(0, Nx):
            if(i <= Nx*Ny*normaldist(i, j, Nx, Ny, xp, yp, SG)):
                mask[i, j] = normaldist(i, j, Nx, Ny, xp, yp, SG)
    return mask
Nx = 200  # lattice size X
Ny = 200  # lattice size Y
distributionG2 = np.zeros((Nx, Ny))
for j in range(0, Ny):
    for i in range(1, Nx-1):
        if (j == 0):
            distributionG2 += distributionG(Nx, Ny, i, j, SG=1)
        else:
            rp = random.random()
            if(((distributionG2[i+1, j-1]>0) or (distributionG2[i, j-1]>0)
               or (distributionG2[i-1, j-1]>0)) and rp>0.05):
                if(True):
                    print(i, j, rp)
                distributionG2 += distributionG(Nx, Ny, i, j, SG=1)
```

Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really get whats going on, but I think I would generate the gaussian mask just one time and shift it to where it needs to be by cropping it and filling with zeros/ones. Its not exactly the same as what your doing but the difference is very small and I think it will be much faster.

Comment: Could you describe your problem more, so we could help you. Also please if you convert variable names to english, more people would understand.

Comment: I am trying to place 2D-Gaussian-like distributions randomly centered in an array with a certain probability. The point is that the process of generating these Gaussians and placing its values in the array takes too long. @Bas